# padding the 3D images for deformation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to pad a 3D image for the deformation process. i want to know if i am padding 3D images of dimension 256*256*150 and after applying padding my dimension become 656*656*150 . should i try to pad the third dimension also i.e 150 before applying any process on a padded image?

I am using MATLAB for padding

```
mask_im=padarray(image_mask,[2*window_size_pad 2*window_size_pad],'both');
```

if it is necessary to pad the third dimension , then what should i use to pad that ..i have seen the Matlab pad array dimension and it doesn't say anything about the third dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a rotation along the third axis, no need to pad the third dimension... You should pad every dimension where you wish to apply a frequency domain transform. 
Best way to pad them all is probably to permute the axis

```
B = permute(A,[1,3,2])
```

pad, then permute back

```
A = permute(B,[1,3,2])
```